# Error al enviar formulario PHP y JS

Tags: javascript, php, formularios, phpmailer

Estoy validando un formulario con Javascript pero al tratar de enviar la información obtenida con PHPMailer, el servidor manda el siguiente error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Ya he verificado las urls y todo parece estar en orden:

**Formulario.html**

```
<form method="post" class="box contact-valid" id="contact-form" autocomplete="off">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre(s) y Apellidos*" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electrónico *" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" name="note"  id="note" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-st">Enviar mensaje</button>
                                        <div id="loader">
                                            <i class="fas fa-sync"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="error-messages">
                                            <div id="success">
                                                <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>Gracias, tu mensaje ha sido enviado. Pronto me pondre en contacto contigo.
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="error">
                                                <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Se produjo un error al enviar mensaje. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**validarFormulario.js**

```
if ($("#contact-form").length) {
    $("#contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },

            email: "required",
            
        },

        messages: {
            name: "Por favor ingresa tu nombre",
            email: "Por favor ingresa tu correo electr贸nico"
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $( "#loader").hide();
                    $( "#success").slideDown( "slow" );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $( "#success").slideUp( "slow" );
                    }, 3000);
                    form.reset();
                },
                error: function() {
                    $( "#loader").hide();
                    $( "#error").slideDown( "slow" );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $( "#error").slideUp( "slow" );
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

**mail.php**

```
 <?php
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['note'];

  
   $to = 'contacto@midominio.com';
   $subject = 'Mensaje desde el sitio web';
   $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
   $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   
   echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

 }

?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133591/discussion-on-question-by-suri-gangs-hallen-error-al-enviar-formulario-php-y-js).

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo comento @masterguru la URL del archivo js en la función AJAX no hace referencia a la ubicación correcta, en todo casi sería

```
url: "js/mail.php"
```